# Term for person who forgets directions or routes

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do we call a person who easily forgets directions or routes?

I googled but couldn't find any appropriate term.

Comment: I would say that person is uncoordinated.

Comment: "Lost" *::rimshot::*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally I just say someone (me, let's say, just hypothetically) **has "a bad (terrible) sense of direction."**

Apparently a more serious condition exists that causes sufferers to get lost even on common paths and turned around in their own houses. This is called **developmental topographical disorientation** and is described in [this news feature](http://www.usatoday.com/news/health/painter/2008-10-19-your-health_N.htm).

Answer (score 4):

The traditional phrase used is that these people have ***no sense of direction.*** But ajk's answer of ***"directionally challenged"*** is a great way to make this phrase into an adjective.

Answer (score 3):

In my family, we call those people ***directionally challenged***.