# Word for person who can't remember paths?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Term for person who forgets directions or routes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43972/term-for-person-who-forgets-directions-or-routes)
>   [Is there a specific word for describing a person who gets lost easily?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-there-a-specific-word-for-describing-a-person-who-gets-lost-easily)

What to call a person who can't remember paths and roads?

Comment: Geographically challenged

Comment: Directionally challenged.

Comment: "Found starved to death in the woods"

Answer (score 3):

[Topographic disorientation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topographical_disorientation) is the usual term for this sort of thing, assuming it’s not just the occasional getting lost we all suffer from time to time. It comes in various flavors.

You can also learn more about it from a first-person perspective [here](http://www.cpr.org/#load_article|Her_World_Turns_90).

I’ve also heard *topographic amnesia*, but I’m not sure that one has general currency.

Answer (score 2):

A person who isn't good at finding their way around has *no sense of direction*, and may often end up *lost*.